# VLC player codecs

Tags: vlc-media-player, video-codecs

I got a tablet for X-mas (windows 8) and tried to play some video with VLC on it and most won't play mp4 mkv etc, on my laptop the same files will play in VLC, so I assume it to be a codec problem

I have installed the k-lite codec pack and still no go, am I missing something here?

Thanks Maddie

Comment: Does not it have built-in player?

Comment: yeah it does, however the built in player has the same issues

Comment: call me thick, but where do i find that settings screen?

Comment: Open VLC Player > Tools > Preferences > Video Settings > http://fud.community.services.support.microsoft.com/Fud/FileDownloadHandler.ashx?fid=f0856420-fef3-41d9-8234-03e22c2a699d

Comment: VLC usually will not use external codecs unless instructed to do so, and instead uses codecs built into the application. KLite is great for WMP and MPC, but does nothing for VLC. you might want to try removing everything and then trying VLC with no additional codecs.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. because the video files did not play in vlc i installed the codec pack. i even tried the nightly version of vlc, but nothing i try seems to work. The weird thing is, the same file plays on my laptop, with the same version of VLC...

Comment: Try [VideoLan support](http://www.videolan.org/support/)